# User account seems to be created for the purpose of advertisement

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

I've noticed a few answers by [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/51044/sweet72) user. While they are not all *incorrect* (one of them is), a few of them are incomplete (One or two are not *wrong*, but they don't answer the question at all). However, that is not my problem.

When I checked this user's bio, I saw that it is being used for advertisement of a company! The creation of this user's account seems to be for advertisement. They seem to answer questions so that attention is drawn to the person's page and subsequently their bio and the company.

I don't really know if this is an issue, but I thought I should bring it to your notice, so any necessary action can be taken.

Comment: You can put whatever you want (unless its offensive) in your profile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spam is an issue in posts: questions, answers, comments, chat, flags, etc. We do not really police the profile for spam.

No offense meant to the new user, but if they are trying to drive people to their company website by creating interest with good answers to questions, they're doing it wrong. This looks to me more like an earnest individual who is not at all an English language language expert but is trying to help.

The best thing you can do in this case is provide *constructive* criticism in comments on answers, up- and downvote, etc.

Answer (score 4):

If a new user is submitting helpful posts out of a desire to get people looking at a profile page and subsequently buying something, then I say good luck to him; (cf. [this xkcd strip](http://xkcd.com/810/)). In practice, barely anybody will be persuaded to spend money by your mastery of the English language (alas), and the time spent will be disproportionate; but that's his problem, not ours. Again, such a poster may well be tempted, when the inefficiency of this method starts to show, to cut corners, plagiarize and commit other heinous crimes; but if so the problem is the behaviour, not the original reason. **All posters should be judged on the quality of submissions, not motive, background or intention**.

(This rather pompous message comes direct to your computer courtesy of TimLymington plc. Why not try our range of vocabulary enlargers *today*?)

Comment: My vocabulary used to be so pathetically tiny that no one was interested in what I had to say. Thanks to the TimLymington patented Vocabuhancinator™, I got a new job, a new pair of shoes, *and* a free ice cream cone!

Comment: The fact that you ended the name with 'inator' (y) !! ;D

Answer (score 2):

I had actually come to meta this evening to post the same question about the same user.

I would only add that, of his several contributions I've seen today, several offer dubious, or even clearly incorrect, advice - and include grammatical mistakes and incorrect language constructions.  Yes, he may well be trying to help as @MετάEd has said, although his 'help' and advice is often wrong, but I guess there's not a lot we can do about that except by providing 'better' advice!